# in-app purchase, any difference between iOS 5 and 6?

Tags: ios, compatibility, in-app-purchase

I searched, only found a similar question, which was not quite answered, and mine is not the same, so I ask here.

I followed Troy IAP tutorial (http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) and coded my IAP, which works well in iOS 6.0 Simulator or real non-jail-break testing device. However, when I tested in iOS 5.0/5.1 Simulator (I don't have 5.x device), IAP process went through all steps to payment queue and returned stateFailed. The program otherwise runs well in iOS 5.x, except IAP.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i also face same issue and yes ask question here and i found this answer.

[You cannot reliably test In App Purchase in the iOS5 Simulator. You need to test it on a device.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432805/in-app-purchase-not-working-in-ios-5/15432869?noredirect=1#comment21828261_15432869)