# iOS in-app purchase store visible to emulator but not in actual device

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, simulator

I'm trying to configure an app store and the store items are visible in the emulator, but not when using the actual device.

What am I missing?

Thx.

Edit: I signed out from the real account and now the store requres me to enter an existing apple ID. However when I enter the test apple ID, it gets me through the validation,credit card etc. What to do?

Edit 2: It works in iOS 6.0 simulator. The problem is in iOS 5.1 in both simulator and device.

Comment: hard to tell with such a broad question without any code. -- oh and...  The payment queue is not available in Simulator. Attempting to retrieve the payment queue logs a warning.

Comment: On your real device, make sure you log out of the Store with your real iTunes account and login with whatever test account you setup. BTW - It's a simulator, not an emulator.

Comment: it might also be due to the device using the appstore sandbox > depending on provisioning profile

Comment: I 've already signed out from the real account. The docs say I should not login to the store using the test account.  Should I?

Comment: I signed out from the real account and now the store requres me to enter an existing apple ID. However when I enter the test apple ID, it gets me through the validation,credit card etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your test account to replace your real account on your device. Yes, you will be prompted to enter credit card etc. What I did was just quit at that step, now you testing account will be on the device, but not in itunes system, which is fine, I think, since testing account just use sandbox environment. Also, you need test your app in a testing device which need provision file.

Comment: is your device a testing one with provision file?

Comment: I read your update. I think you had the same problem I had, check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597263/in-app-purchase-any-difference-between-ios-5-and-6

Comment: I can buy IAP from my app in ios6 but not ios5.x, same as your problem. To answer your "Does that matter", right, you can only test IAP in certified testing device --- yes, Apple definitely a control freak.

Comment: Well I have an apple $99 membership so I guess my device is certified.
However what can I do? It works in iOS 6.0 emulator, does that mean that the final version users won't be able to purchase unless running iOS 6?

Comment: No, your device does not automatically become a certified testing device. You need add it, check developer.apple.com and read some the guide. Please check and update us, particularly 1, I'm interested if you have the same problem as I have (ios6 vs ios5.x); 2, accept my anser --- I'll add testing device part into my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Found It.
AppSync caused the issue. Remove it, and the sandbox environement will work as expected.

Best Regards.