# In-App-Purchase not working in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

i have successfully integrated in app purchase in my app.i have follow [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) tutorial for in app purchase.it working fine with iOS 6. but when i try to test it on ios 5.1 simulator than every time i try to login to buying the product i just get the bellow error.

**Transaction error: An unknown error has occurred**

and yes my mac keyboard is also not working when i am testing it on ios 5.1 simulator i have to input from simulator keypad.

Comment: I have also same problem and not get any solution of this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot reliably test In App Purchase in the iOS5 Simulator. You need to test it on a device.

And the keyboard not working for In App Purchase login used to be bloody annoying.

Comment: That is an improvement for the iOS6 Simulator. Apple warns against testing in the simulator ever, but much to most dev's surprise the iOS6 simulator works against that warning.

Comment: Until you test on a device and get the exact same error at the exact same time, you can't reliably expect it to be your fault.

Comment: You're welcome to post code and we'll take a blind look to see if there is anything out of the ordinary but I suspect its simulator issues since iOS5 simulator doesn't work with StoreKit.